# ruby on rails css behaviour

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, margin

im working on a rails project version 3 and i can't figure out how this happens.
there is no css since this is a brand new project.

**why do i get this margin?** 
is this a rails convention?

is there any standard css used by rails if you do not set up a reset-css-file?

**chrome:**

[image: margin in chrome]

**this is how the html gets generated by rails:**

[image: html structure]

Comment: What does your HTML/CSS debugging tool tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome applies a default property of `body { margin: 8px; }` to all webpages that don't specify their own margins.

Comment: why? is it possible to turn it off? since i actually don't want to work with a reset style-sheet. (@devin)

Comment: The only way to turn it off, is to specify your own margin. If you don't want an entire CSS reset (though I recommend one, since it'll make all browsers render your page nearly identical), you can just add a css property of `body { margin: 0px; }` to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Many browsers have default styles that may change how elements are displayed by default. If you want to start from an clean slate you should look into using a CSS reset style sheet. I prefer [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) by Eric Meyer, however there are others you can look into using.